# Java: how to detect the real, unfakeable user language and user country?

Tags: java, locale

For our Java application, we are considering to toughen our licensing conditions and related code for certain countries for which we are experiencing massive license infringement. Therefore we want to find out the *real* user language and user country. I'm aware, that you can query system properties `user.language` and `user.country`, but these can easily be faked when starting the Java application using e.g. `-Duser.language=en`. Is there a way to detect the original, unaltered values for these properties? Or is there another API which gives us the *real* settings?

Note:

- the solution should require only a small computational effort and no Internet connection
- we are not looking for a perfectly safe solution, but it also shouldn't be too easy to fake (like with system properties).

Comment: you could try geolocation, but that's not 100% reliable (by far)

Comment: As I am quite sure you are not able to find a reliable way of figuring out where a user is located wouldn't it be easier to have the user confirm his place of origin? If the user uses incorrect information here he is at fault and you should be safe from legal consequences. Combine this with a "simple" method such as using the system properties and you should in theory be fine or?

But I think this is a topic you should discuss with your lawyers and not stackoverflow tbh.

Comment: @Stultuske I'm afraid that geolocation will be too costly/computational expensive; I've refined the notes

Comment: 'costly/computational expensive'? not really. but it is far from complete and will only find the 'locations' your database contains. Even then, it's still unreliable.

Comment: @Ben as noted it must not be perfectly reliable. For example, for Windows it would be fine to get the _real_ configured locale/language. If the user will change it, then we may fail and that's fine. But changing locale/language will have many disadvantages and effects on other Software, so don't think many would do that just to save a few bucks.

Comment: Unless you speak to them in person, no way would be reliable. But you might consider trying to hardwire your software to hardware, make locale a hardware-bound and unchangeable.

Comment: @Stultuske geolocation require e.g. to know the "external" IP, right? I don't think this is usually available. Either way, do you know of a Java library for that purpose?

Comment: @mstrap I tried one (which runs completely locally) but all depends on how reliable your database with locations/ip matchings is and how sure that their subdomains don't "shadow" other domains' subdomains, ...

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks, but I'm looking for a significantly less elaborate approach than hardware copy-protection.

Comment: You could try wrapping your java application somehow so that the user is simply not able (without additional effort) to start it using the `-Duser.language=en` command maybe?

Comment: Discriminating customers based on culture (you are essentially checking for language and locale settings, not residence) is racist and unethical. Do not do it.

Comment: @Stultuske I still don't understand how that could work. On my machine, I can only see IP address: 192.168.92.20.

Comment: @giorgiga it is not racist it is neccessary to abide by local laws.

Comment: @giorgiga race and country is not the same. there is no racism here, they don't want to limit based on "colour of skin", but based on "bought a license or not". nothing racist, nothing illegal.

Comment: @Stultuske, if they bought a license, what does it matter where they are from? If they didn't, it actually also doesn't matter.

Comment: @mstrap indeed, and somewhere on your own server you can have a db that matches ip's with locations (like this: http://www.baeldung.com/geolocation-by-ip-with-maxmind) you can extend the data with ip'addresses you are sure are safe, but still .. the IP addresses are only unique in a network, there might be a network in country A with an identical ip as one in country B (only seperated by the domain in which it is hosted)

Comment: @Ben sounds interesting. On Windows, we are using a native executable launcher which might be helpful. On OSX, Linux we are using just shell scripts which are (too) easy to manipulate.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The problem is that certain licenses are not usable in certain countries depending on local laws regarding copyright and such. Saying "they bought a license, so it does not matter" would be great but sadly is not always correct.

The correct way would be to use a license that explicitely makes sure that you are not allowed to use the software when your local laws do not apply to its terms and services.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov fastening checks on places where you are aware is (much) more infringment, though onorthodox, is not racist. unless the claim is that the people are violating the rights because they are of that specific race, which is a claim I have not heard mstrap make.

Comment: @Stultuske, even these types of geolocation checks are horrible. Imagine half your apps becoming unusable as soon as you cross the border. Oh, what's that sound? It's the sound of all those apps being excahnged for competitor's apps.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov so your point is allowing people to break laws is better (because it is simpler)?

Comment: @Stultuske, if *they* broke laws, it's quite different from when *you* broke them. If the law forbids selling the app in the country, you just take measures of not selling the app. If it doesn't, but you license states that you take no responsibility for using the app if the law forbids it, then they read it and they agreed. This is a lawyer's domain from there.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It's about using software illegally in the wrong country without paying for it. Back to the question: how to solve that problem technically - without a lawyer?

Comment: Hmm, what do you call *the real language and user country*? A friend of mine is German, lives in France and his computer is configured as en-us. What would you want in that use case?

Comment: @SergeBallesta en-us is a locale, but not a location necessarily. The location on your friend should be picked up as "France", since that's where he lives

Comment: @ThomasS. the technical way would be, as I said from the start, is you setup a Skype call or whatever with them, and do an interview. Once that's done, you file their language in your database.

Comment: But you do bring up a good point. You can't really decide anything on language: Belgium has 3 languages (and those are only the official languages), not taken into account the x amount of other languages spoken/used

Comment: @M.Prokhorov since that is nonsense, and doesn't help anything, that is not the 'technical way' to solve this. I can speak english, doesn't mean I live even  remotely near an english speaking country. They also want a way that excludes fraudulent information, which can not be achieved by 'let's just ask them and assume they don't lie'

Comment: @Stultuske “*The location on your friend should be picked up as "France", since that's where he lives*”—and how does a computer know?

Comment: @Holger exactly THAT is the question :)

Comment: @Stultuske, and the answer is: computer asked the user and assumed they didn't lie. Here we come to the start.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no, that's your start. if you assume that computers can in no way tell where something is coming from, you are blind. You think that NSA is able to zoom in on your computer because they asked you where live? ... Yes, that's how those dudes operate.

Comment: @Stultuske, there are other ways, we suggested them all: 1. ask user. 2. use geolocation. 3. Rely on hardware to have a kind of copy-protection which would say "I'm selling these only in country X, so if you have one, you must also be from there".

Comment: I suppose you could also ask NSA to tell you how they do it. I doubt *that*'ll appear as a StackOverflow answer though.

Comment: heh :) That, I would like to see, though ;)

Comment: @Stultuske there seems to be a misunderstanding. The NSA might be able to access your computer and inspect all data on it, but, of course, that does not imply being able to get information not being stored on the computer. Since the data will be finally inspected by a human investigator, (s)he will likely be able to determine your true location from the personal information found on your computer or deduced from cross-checking with your cell phone’s data or whatever, but that does mean that a single software could determine the true geolocation of the computers it is running on.

Comment: without the application calling the 'mothership' to verify its IP (and therefore some geo information) all measures are futile. With IP address to locale mapping you will not detect VPN connections. 
The application does not need to stop running when it detects no connection - just degrade gradually insisting on establishing a connection.

Comment: *for certain countries for which we are experiencing massive license infringement*, MY country would be 100% in that list, as someone who buys software, always (unless open-source is present for the functionality I need), I salute the intention for this

Comment: @diginoise there are multinational ISPs using the same range of dynamically assigned IPs for all customers, making it impossible to map from an IP to an actual location. And you would need to update the mappings fast enough, even for national ISPs. I always find it funny, where websites locate me due to my IP.

Comment: @Holger they'll be able to get the IP, and that of the network you're connected on. They most likely do what they do by having a chat with your internet provider. So yes, there are ways to do this, but they are not really applicable here, since they would be far from efficiënt, and the OP would not have the legal power to force providers to give out information about ip's.

Comment: @Stultuske it is possible for authorities to to query the IP that has been identified as the origin of certain activities and for that, it doesn’t matter that the owner has a different IP by the time the authorities get the result, but that doesn’t help the OP to get the owner’s location in realtime. By the time, I go online, the OP can’t know the mapping of the IP to a location, because it doesn’t exist yet. Unless they are fine with “Europe” as an answer. As said, I regularly see where website locate me, it’s usually off by more than thousand kilometers (that’s much in central Europe).

Comment: @Holger i know it's not bomb-proof. Interesting engineering problem none-the less. You could go further than IP address only, and do `traceroute`  to the IP address presented and have some thresholds for the IPs found along the path. Multinational ISP at some point jumps down to a national trunk (perhaps ... ) ;)

Answer (score 7):

Do not even try. You are trying to solve at a technical level a legal question. I once used a Linux machine where different users had different declared languages and time zones, and still have a VM using "C" language et UTC time zone.

As per my experience, such controls can annoy well intentioned users that happen to use a non standard configuration, but cannot prevent someone to deliberately give a wrong information.

So my advice is:

- use the system property to get the declared country
- ask the user to confirm or change it
- trust what user declared

It could save you number of hotline calls.

Comment: I could not agree more to be honest. Leave it to your lawyers to figure out how to deal with people abusing your license. It is not something you should deal with as a softwaredeveloper in a perfect world (although it's obviously way nicer for your boss to just tell you: Make sure it won't even be a legal issue)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I asked our layers via an official email, of something we might be taking into consideration for the next version and their short response was - "Oh boy, this is like asking for trouble", whatever that means :)